# How to add Enterprise custom field to display actual costs from a different DB in Project Server?

Tags: olap, project-server, olap-cube, project-server-2007

I am trying wrap my head around how data is being served to Project Server.

I am trying match up a value (actual cost) to project lines in an Executive View of Project Center which displays each project.  This actual cost comes from another database; the accounting database.

I am assuming I have to build it in an OLAP Cube.

Anyways, I would like to know if anyone knows how to link the cube to the enterprise custom field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is you can't.

Either use OLAP or inject into SQL the modifications.